# Concrete5 Block Attributes

Tags: concrete5

I have a few images on a homepage, and I want the client to be able to change the images from time to time. Right now they are hard coded as:

`<img src="<?=$this->getThemePath()?>/img/welcomePhoto1.jpg" alt="" class="welcome-photo" />`

If I set this to a new block area where they can change the photo, can I make sure that every time they change the images the block will retain the class. I don't really like adding classes through the UI (just don't feel that's a good practice). I know you can wrap blocks like this:

```
<?php 
$a = new Area('sidebar');
$a->setBlockWrapperStart('<div class="box">');
$a->setBlockWrapperEnd('</div>');
$a->display($c); 
?>
```

Is their something like `$a->setBlockClass('welcome-photo');`?

Comment: Using setBlockWrapperStart and setBlockWrapperEnd like you do in your code sample is the proper way to do this in C5. What is the problem you're having with that approach?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, there might be a way to achieve what you are trying to do via the setCustomTemplate method for the Area class.

```
$m = new Area('Main');
$m->setCustomTemplate('image','templates/welcome-photo.php');
$m->display($c);
```

Then within your templates/welcome-photo.php file, you can set a wrapper around those images as you want. Be advised, though, that this just sets a default template for any block of type 'image' (in this example) in that area, but it CAN be overridden through the editing interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with using `setBlockWrapperStart()` and `setBlockWrapperEnd()` -- this is what they're for.

But if you want an alternate solution for some reason, you could hardcode a file set instead and have the user swap out the images of that set via the File Manager.

Or you could hardcode a scrapbook block (if using 5.4 or lower) or a Stack (if using 5.5 or higher) and have the user edit the image via the dashboard scrapbook (5.4) or dashboard Stacks (5.5) screen.

If you want code samples for either of those approaches, let me know and I'll amend my answer with that. But please explain the issue with your original setBlockWrapper approach first, so I understand the specific problem you're having.

Comment: I was just wanting to add the class to the `img` elements without throwing them all in div's, to keep the code output cleaner. I don't need the `setBlockWrapperStart` and `setBlockWrapperEnd`, I was just wondering if there was a similar approach to that, where you could make each element have that class. Sorry if I'm not being clear enough. It of course makes sense in my mind, but I can't explain it I guess! :)

Comment: There is no way to set the class of a block from the template itself because every block has different HTML output. BUT, you can customize the template of the image block. Copy `SITEROOT/concrete/blocks/image/view.php` to `SITEROOT/blocks/image/view.php` (you'll need to create the blocks/image directory first), then edit the file there and modify the HTML. But I don't think it's that bad to have a wrapper div around the blocks -- I understand your tastes may vary though.